# Angular / .net mvc app hosted on azure does not load svg-s after angular 7 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis, svg, webpack

I've been banging my head around this one all afternoon.

I have a hybrid app, asp.net mvc on the backend and angular on the frontend. We used the `index.cshtml` to load the angular app but after upgrading to angular 7 it no longer loads certain `svg` files when it is in production mode.

Apparently after upgrading to angular 7, when it builds the bundle for production, it spits out the svg files which are referenced in the scss like this `background-image: url('../../../../../assets/icons/A08_16_info.svg')` directly into the dist folder:

[image]

Funny thing is that the svg's which are referenced directly in the template with inline style work just fine and the images remain in the assets folder. This looks like some webpack optimization.

This is how I reference the angular files inside asp.net mvc index.cshtml:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileEntries = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
List<string> bundles = new List<string>();

fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/dist"));

bundles.Add("runtime.");
bundles.Add("polyfills");
bundles.Add("styles.");
bundles.Add("scripts.");
bundles.Add("main.");
bundles.Add("*.svg");
}

@foreach (string bundleName in bundles)
{
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(fileName);
        if (fileInformation.Name.Contains(bundleName))
        {
            if (fileInformation.Name.Contains("styles"))
            {
                <link href="~/Scripts/dist/@fileInformation.Name" rel="stylesheet" />
            }
            else if (fileInformation.Name.Contains(".js"))
            {
                <script src="~/Scripts/dist/@fileInformation.Name"></script>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the browser console:

[image]

This looks like an `IIS` issue. I've tried adding the following rule to the `web.config` file but nothing happens:

```
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  </staticContent>
```

If anyone stumbled into this issue after upgrading to angular 7, I would really appreciate an idea to work around this.

Regards!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Learn the sub status before moving on.

Comment: Thanks ! I enabled detailed errors and apparently IIS is looking for those images inside wwwroot instead of dist.
Now the question is how to tell IIS to look for them inside dist or tell angular to disable adding their paths to dist.
This is my directory structure on azure: wwwroot -> Scripts -> dist